# How to get TextStyles/Attributes (fontColor, fontFamily, etc.) of a Googlesheet cell in AppScript, then set it in a Table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, attributes, google-sheets-api

I have a Script in Googlesheets that is suposed to use the sheet as a modifiable template (colors and font should be modifiable), it copies it and paste it as a Table in GoogleSlides. It copies each cell one by one and then it puts it in the slide table cell. My problem is right now i could only get it to copy the text and background color of each cell, not the fontFamily, nor the fontColor.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
var slidesPage = SlidesApp.openById(slideID).getSlides()[slideBegin];
var rows = values.length;
var columns = values[0].length;
var table = slidesPage.insertTable(rows, columns);


for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
    var cell = table.getCell(r, c);
    cell.getText().setText(values[r][c]);
    cell.getFill().setSolidFill(backgrounds[r][c]);
    var alignment;
    switch(horizontalAlignments[r][c]) {
      case "general-left":
        alignment = SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.START;
        break;
      case "general-right":
        alignment = SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.END;
        break;
      case "center":
        alignment = SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.CENTER;
        break;
    }
    //cell.getText().getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(alignment);
  }
}
```

I have tried with .getAttributes or stuff like that, but i cant find how is it supposed to go. I know i probably have to set a "var" with the attributes and then add something like cell.getAttributes().setAttributes() but not sure, im completly stuck.

Comment: In your situation, are you required to retrieve the "fontFamily" and "fontColor" from the cells including only the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Slides but in Spreadsheet the thing you want is `getRichTextValue()` and [Class TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style)

You can get the attributes from a text in a cell about this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var text   = ss.getRange('a1').getRichTextValue() // .getRuns()[0];
  var style  = text.getTextStyle();
  var size   = style.getFontSize()
  var family = style.getFontFamily();
  var color  = style.getForegroundColor();
  var bold   = style.isBold();
  var italic = style.isItalic();
  // etc
  console.log(size, family, bold, italic, color);
}
```

**Update**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range

Surprisingly I see no methods `set...` in `TextRange` object in Slides except the `setText(text)`! There are the `get...` methods but they're quite useless if you can't apply these attributes.

It looks like this part of Slides App API is not ready yet.

Comment: Okay, but this creates the variable, you know how to apply it then?

Comment: I do. But for SpreadsheetApp and for DocumentsApp only. I don't know how to change font attributes in Slides. I suppose it's about all the same. `var size = text_in_spreadsheet.getFontSize()` then `text_in_slides.setFontSize(size)`. Something like this.